# How to replace an audio stream in a video file with multiple audio streams?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, streaming

I want to replace the second audio stream (0:2) in a video file that has two audio streams and give it a label if possible. How would I go about this? All the ffmpeg commands I found won't let me keep the second audio stream.

Answer (score 28):

Use the [`-map` option](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) to choose your streams. Default [stream selection](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) will only choose one of each stream type, so that is why `-map` has to be used.

## Replace second audio stream

[image]

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -i audio.mp3 -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 1:a \
-metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -metadata:s:a:1 language=sme -codec copy \
-shortest output.mkv
```

- `0:v` – The `0` refers to the first input which is `video.mkv`. The `v` means "select video stream type".
- `0:a:0` – The `0` refers to the first input which is `video.mkv`. The `a` means "select audio stream type". The last `0` refers to the first audio stream from this input. If only `0:a` is used, then all video streams would be mapped.
- `1:a` – The `1` refers to the second input which is `audio.mp3`. The `a` means "select audio stream type".
- `-codec copy` will [stream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (re-mux) instead of encode. If you need a specific audio codec, you should specify `-c:v copy` (to keep the video) and then, for example, `-c:a libmp3lame` to re-encode the audio stream to MP3.
- `-shortest` will end the output when the shortest input ends.

## Combine two audio streams into one

[image]

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mkv -i aud.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" \
-map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -ac 2 \
-shortest out.mp4
```

- Filtering requires re-encoding, and the [`amerge` filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge) is used here, so the audio can not be stream copied in this example.

Comment: didn't work for me at all.

Comment: @omouse "didn't work" is hard to provide help for. You should use a pastebin link to show your command and the complete console output.

Comment: My issue is the `-codec copy`, but I fixed that (different version of ffmpeg), the other issue I had was with with the `-map`, it complained about the wrong number of streams.

Comment: I just used `-map 0:v -map 1:a`. I assume this means to take the video from the first file (video.mkv) and then take the audio from the second file (audio.mp4) to create output.mkv ... Not sure what the `-map 0:a:0` is for. I excluded it and I get the results I wanted.

Comment: @sunk818 Same here. Didn’t work with `-map 0:a:0`, so I removed it and the result was fine.

Comment: @aaronk6 The original question requested a way to map **multiple audio streams** to the output. The example takes the first audio stream from the first input, and the audio stream(s) from the second input and maps them to the output. It appears some are assuming that the example makes an output with a **single audio stream** and are then confused.

Comment: @aaronk6 Added an example to combine two input stereo audio streams into one output stereo stream.