# Replacing ALL audio streams of a video in ffmpeg but keep meta

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I already found [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/800234/how-to-replace-an-audio-stream-in-a-video-file-with-multiple-audio-streams) but the answer doesn't really say much about replacing more than one audio track. I quite don't understand the -map things he does in there and I would just like to replace 5 audio streams with 5 of my own.

I want to keep the meta data of the original file, I want to keep the naming of the streams and everything else but the actual audio stream. I know this has to be possible somehow with ffmpeg, I've been able to achieve what I wanted with `Subler` but I can't tell my users to download Subler every time they want to convert something which is why I want to find a fitting `ffmpeg` command.

Basically I want to keep the container "layout" and codecs but just edit the contents of it without modifying anything else

Comment: Please show the complete console output of: `ffmpeg -i original -i audio1 -i audio2 -i audio3`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ok what I've eventually done is removing all the audio tracks in Subler, adding that "almost empty" container to my application and used MP4Box' `add` command to fill in the audio again. No ffmpeg needed here