# How to merge external audio track with internal audio track from video file using FFmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

We have this multimedia files:

- a video `video.mp4`

  - `video track 0`
  - `audio track 0` is audio we don't want
  - `audio track 1` is audio we want
- an audio `audio.mp3` track

How to use `ffmpeg` with this video and

- just put there `audio.mp3`
- and mix it with `audio track 1` of this video, because we don't want `audio track 0` of this video

And in final to have `output.mp4` where:

- Video is `video.mp4`
- `audio track 1` from `video.mp4` + `audio.mp3`. **Audio as one track, merged, mixed.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace an audio stream in a video file with multiple audio streams?](https://superuser.com/questions/800234/how-to-replace-an-audio-stream-in-a-video-file-with-multiple-audio-streams)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i video -i audio -filter_complex "[0:a:1][1:a]amix[a]" -map 0:v -c:v copy -map "[a]" -c:a aac output.mp4
```

The amix filter will mix the 2nd audio track of the video with the audio of the 2nd input. Duration of audio will be same as duration of the longer audio track in the mix.